# Mistakenly performed continuity test on the supply voltage (+12V). How can I determine if my multimeter was damaged?

Tags: multimeter, continuity

I was testing continuity with ground in a breadboarded circuit and accidentally touched the supply rail (12V). My multimeter is a greenlee dm-820a. Everything seems to be working fine, but I am concerned that I may have damaged the meter. Is there any way for me to determine whether this is the case? The manual for the meter makes no mention of such a situation. Thanks.

Comment: I do the same mistake -very- often, with many different multimeters, not yet broken any  for decades,.

Comment: It's fine. Don't worry.

Comment: The manual does mention it, in the "overload protection" section.

Comment: If this were enough to kill a multimeter, I'd have cooked a LOT of them... lucky me!

Comment: *Everything working fine?* Did you check that ohms still works properly?

Comment: @glen_geek Good point. I should have thought more carefully about what that statement meant. No, I hadn't checked. I've done so just now, on a 220 and 100k resistor, and the meter is reading correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between a $10 harbor freight meter and a $70 to $200 Greeenlee meter. The extra components on the PCB of the Greenlee do something, right?  Protection of the circuit and the user. Your meter is fine. Especially since you didn't find anything wrong with it.